# comparison of [type] with [other_type] failed on Rails 4, postgresql with hstore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-postgresql, hstore

When doing an upgrade from `Rails 3`, `postgresql` with `activerecord-postgres-hstore` gem to `Rails 4`, `postgresql` and native Rails 4 `hstore`, I started getting masses of issues with tests failing (which passed before the upgrade) due to type mismatches e.g.

> comparison of String with 0 failed

Answer (score 0):

**tldr**
Postgresql stores all its data as strings but the `activerecord-postgres-hstore` gem allowed you to define a type as part of the accessor e.g.

```
hstore :data, :accessors => { old_weight: :decimal }
```

whereas the native `hstore` in `Rails 4` will not allow you to define type so any non-string comparisons (etc) will fail. Hard.

So *when upgrading to Rails 4 and converting to native hstore*, any comparisons or expectations of type will have to be converted/enforced.